Syntactic use of italian si
I am trying to learn Italian through the trilingual edition Nuovo Testamento interlineare (in Ancient Greek, Latin and Italian; I know the first two). In Matth. 1, 18 we read sua madre Maria si era fidanzata con Giuseppe. I would like to ask what is the syntactic role of si. As far as I know, si is mainly a reflexive pronoun but I cannot imagine its specific function here. (Perhaps it has to do with the v. fidanzare, though I would like an explanation; when this word appears as a v. complement?)
Thanks a lot.

See https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fidanzare/ : “Più spesso rifl.”

@DaG thank you for your comment, but this doesn' t answer my question; you quote an entry, which gives the meaning of the particular use of fidanzare.

Indeed, that was not an answer, just a comment.

In Italian (and many other languages, most prominently Romance and Slavic), there's a concept of reflexive verbs.
Reflexive verbs have the local version of the reflexive pronoun (si in the case of Italian) slapped at the end of their infinitive forms. This pronoun is then being used in the finite forms of the verb as well.
Depending on the language, it may or may not detach from the verb in finite forms, and may or may not be required to agree in gender, number, and person with the subject of the verb. In Old Russian, it had to detach and had to agree; in Modern Russian, it doesn't detach and doesn't agree; in Italian it may or may not detach (depending on several factors) but always has to agree. The si that you are seeing here is a detached part of the reflexive verb fidanzarsi "to get engaged" that agrees with the subject (sua madre Maria) in person and number.
It's a purely syntactic feature. Some verbs in Italian (and other languages with this feature) happen to be reflexive, that's just the way it works.

In many cases (riflessivo proprio) you can kinda define their meaning as "doing something on yourself": ferire "to hurt" / ferirsi "to hurt oneself".

In others, it's a "general change of state" vs "a specific action on someone": sposare "to marry (someone)" vs sposarsi "to get married". The latter doesn't mean "to marry oneself", as surface analysis would suggest.

In others still, they are synonyms with the non-reflexive version. Ricordare and ricordarsi both mean "to remember (something)", both are transitive, i.e. accept a direct object, and, for the most part, are synonyms.

Finally, for some verbs (so-called "deponent verbs"), the non-reflexive version doesn't exist. The verb accorgersi means "to notice" and affarsi "to agree", but *accorgere and *affare don't exist in isolation in modern Italian.

Sometimes, the reflexive and the non-reflexive versions can somewhat diverge in meaning: trovare "to find" / trovarsi "to be located at", mettere "to put" / mettersi "to begin, to set about", etc.


To answer your question: si in your sentence is a marker of a reflexive verb, which is a syntactic feature of the Italian language.

Reflexive verbs are a particular case of the wider concept of "pronominal verbs", that also carry a pronoun with them, but it doesn't have to be reflexive.
Pronominal verbs exist also in English: "to rough it, to beat it, to kill it" etc. It's hard to put your finger on what exactly that "it" is that you beat, rough, or kill, but it has to be there all the same.
The same thing is going on with that si.

Thank you for your detailed answer. It was clear that it is about the middle voice; the problem was the verb's sense. For example in Ancient Greek we have the v. ἀῤῥαβωνίζομαι (to be engaged), which can be seen either as a middle voice v. (I am engaged to smn) or  an apothetic v. (I am engaded +direct object). Thus A. is it possible for us to approach sematically Maria si era fidanzata con Giuseppe as Maria engaged herself to Giuseppe (i.e. the first greek meaning)?

And B. Do we conclude that the syntactic role of si is "marker of a reflexive v."? (I 've never heard this role.) I get confused with the coexistence of a past participle (something passive) and si (something instead direct object). If fidanzata was something active, there would be no problem. So could a view of this si as a dative solve this problem (: Maria was engaged for herself to Giuseppe)? I cannot see something else.

@SK_: it's a syntactic thing, it's not guaranteed that you can derive its meaning from the surface analysis of its parts. With reflexive verbs, the auxiliary verb changes from avere to essere, so we have avevo fidanzato mia figlia a Giuseppe "I had betrothed my daughter to Joseph", but mia figlia si era fidanzata con Giuseppe "my daughter had got engaged with Giuseppe".
